# AngularJs: Replace a part of a string

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way in AngularJs to replace a string?

I'm trying to do something like:

```
{{string.replace('some', 'thing')}}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**your snippet works!**

demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/yNuNeE5yO3rgKAYfGx48?p=preview

**html**

```
<body ng-app="app">
  <div>
    <div class="container" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
      <p>
      {{ name.replace('some', 'thing') }}
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

**js**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);


app.controller('mainCtrl',function($scope) {

    $scope.name = 'this is some';

  }
);
```

the output is `this is thing`

[image]

demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/yNuNeE5yO3rgKAYfGx48?p=preview

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. I tried that before and, I can't remember why, but I didn't think it worked. I searched through Google and I couldn't find anything. After reading your post, I tried it again, and it worked like a charm! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just replace part of the string inside your controller?

So in your view you have: `{{myString}}`

and in your controller you have: `$scope.myString.replace('some', 'thing');`