# angularjs binding replace filter?

Tags: angularjs

angularjs binding replace filter, trying to do

```
<td>
<!-- {{invoice.Number}} -->
{{invoice.SAPCLInvoiceNumber.replace("CL","CL - ")}}
</td>
```

How ever the replace is not working what is the correct syntax for Angular to do this? whats the correct way to do replace?

Comment: Do it within the **control**ler: `$scope.invoice.SAPCLInvoiceNumber = $scope.invoice.SAPCLInvoiceNumber.replace("CL","CL - ");`

Comment: ya try with controller @Waqar

Comment: you need to covert anularjs to angular code ?

Comment: Hope you are using angular 1.x. Your syntax looks fine. Could you add more info to the question? What is the input and desired output? Check the value invoice.SAPCLInvoiceNumber in your screen. For more info about the syntax Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27219097/angularjs-replace-a-part-of-a-string

Answer (score 0):

you can create filter and use it in view :