# How to remove 1000 factor commas from currency pipe in angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, currency-pipe

Is there a way to remove the commas when using Currency pipe?

```html
<div>{{balance | currency }}</div>
```

Output like this - **$7,885,412.00**

I want like this - **$7885412.00**

Comment: You could chain another pipe that removes all the commatas in the currency string

Comment: do you have idea?

Comment: `split(',').join("")`, there might be more ways though

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AngularJs: Replace a part of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27219097/angularjs-replace-a-part-of-a-string)

Comment: no.that is not the answer

Answer (score 5):

You can use Angular Inbuilt `replace` pipe.

```
<div> {{balance | currency | replace:',':''}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, i just made a test app that worked.

generate a pipe using cli, as that will register it for you too with:

```
ng g p noComma
```

inside the no-comma.pipe.ts

replace the transform section with:

```
transform(value: number): string {
    if (value !== undefined && value !== null) {
      return value.toString().replace(/,/g, '');
    } else {
      return '';
    }
  }
```

then in your view,

```
{{ balance | currency | noComma }}
```

Comment: actually i didnt know about replace pipe!, use mkHun's solution! much cleaner